# Send parameters to the currently navigated Android Fragment when using Navigation (jetpack) component, without invoking all lifecycle methods again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parameter-passing, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I do know how to nagivate with the navigate method and send parameters with a bundle,  but would like to figure out how to avoid doing an unnecessary reloading of a fragment i.e. invoking all its lifecycle methods, when it is already loaded, when you just want to update it with some parameter.

I will illustrate what I mean with some code below.
It is a minimal app with two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB, and also two options A and B in the toolbar.
Both fragments only have a text view showing how many times the A and B options has been clicked in the toolbar.

menu/main.xml

```
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_A"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_A"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_B"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_B"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    ...
```

navigation/mobile_navigation.xml:

```
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentA"
        android:name="com.fragmentnavigation.ui.FragmentA"
        android:label="@string/menu_FragmentA"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentB"
        android:name="com.fragmentnavigation.ui.FragmentB"
        android:label="@string/menu_FragmentB"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
    ...
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
    ...
    private var aCounter = 0
    private var bCounter = 0

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val id = item.itemId
        if(id == R.id.action_A) {
            aCounter++
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_fragmentA, bundleOf(Pair(ARG_PARAM_A, aCounter))) // const val ARG_PARAM_A = "paramA"
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_B) {
            bCounter++
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_fragmentB, bundleOf(Pair(ARG_PARAM_B, bCounter))) // const val ARG_PARAM_B = "paramB"
        }
        return true
    }
    ...
```

FragmentA.kt

```
    ...
    private lateinit var textViewA: TextView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val param = arguments?.getInt(ARG_PARAM_A) ?: -1
        setCounterA(param)
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    // I would like to be able to invoke this public method directly from an Activity i.e. without coming from above onViewCreated
    fun setCounterA(a: Int) {
        textViewA.setText(a.toString())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
        textViewA = view.findViewById(R.id.textA)
        return view
    }
    ...
```

and the same kind of code as above for FragmentB.kt (but just replace all "A" with "B")

The above kind of code works BUT it just seems so unnecessary to be forced to trigger all lifecycle methods again even if the fragment is already active.

So, I am looking for a way to do something like below:
MainActivity.kt:

```
    ...
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val id = item.itemId
        if(id == R.id.action_A) {
            aCounter++
            if(isFragmentA_alreadyNavigatedTo()) {
                val fragmentA: FragmentA = getFragmentA_instance()
                fragmentA.setCounterA(aCounter)
            }
            else {
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_fragmentA, bundleOf(Pair(ARG_PARAM_A, aCounter)))
            }
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_B) {
            bCounter++
            if(isFragmentB_alreadyNavigatedTo()) {
                val fragmentB: FragmentB = getFragmentB_instance()
                fragmentB.setCounterB(bCounter)
            }
            else {
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_fragmentB, bundleOf(Pair(ARG_PARAM_B, bCounter)))
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    // How can I implement the below methods from the Activity?
    private fun isFragmentB_alreadyNavigatedTo(): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    private fun getFragmentB_instance(): FragmentB {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    private fun isFragmentA_alreadyNavigatedTo(): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    private fun getFragmentA_instance(): FragmentA {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }   
    ...
```

If it is not possible to get a direct reference to the Fragment instance (as above) to directly invoke the public method,
then is it at least possible to somehow send arguments (e.g. Bundle) in a more indirect way, which can be captured in some event method from the Fragment?
(to avoid having to trigger all the lifecycle methods which seems to be so unnecessary to always be forced to do)